# Completing the array of objects reverse() and sort() button to make it functional when you press it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having difficulty finishing my code. I have an array of objects and I need to use a button to execute the `reverse()` and `sort()` function. I add the buttons to my HTML, but I need help executing the "function" method in my javascript to make the button work on the webpage. I cant figure it out. Someone please help.

HTML Code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Lab 9</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="section"></section>
  <script src="Lab9.js"></script>

  <button onClick="reverse()">Reverse</button>
  <button onClick="sort()">Sort</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code:

```
"use strict";

let motorcycles = [
    {"Color": "Red", "Type": "Honda"}, {"Color": "White", "Type": "Kawasaki"},
    {"Color": "Blue", "Type": "BMW"}, {"Color": "Black", "Type": "Yamaha"},
    {"Color": "Red & White", "Type": "Ducati"}
];

//executes the reverse() function
function reverse() {
    return motorcycles;
}
//executes the sort() function
function sort() {

}

//Unordered List
let ul = '<ul>';

//Looping through the array
for (let index = 0; index < motorcycles.length; index++) {
    let motorcycle = motorcycles[index];
    let motorcycleColor = motorcycle.Color;
    let motorcycleType = motorcycle.Type;

    ul += `<li>${motorcycleColor} ${motorcycleType}</li>`;

    console.log(motorcycleColor);
    console.log(motorcycleType);
}

ul += '</ul>';
document.getElementById("section").innerHTML = ul;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but for the array of objects I need to do if statements in the sort() function.

Comment: what is your sorting variable (ie color, type) ? also what did you try so far? it seems the only thing youve done is go through the array

Comment: the sorting variable is the type and i know i didnt show what i tried, but i dont know how to execute the code inside the function. I just dont know how it goes.

Comment: google 'javascript man documentation'. Bookmark it.  Look for the `Array` (capital A)  class entry. Note `Array.sort` and `Array.reverse` methods already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for looping through the array needs to be inside the function for it to be executed, so your calling the functions reverse and sort but there is nothing in them to be executed that is why you're not getting any result.

```
 function reverse() {
 let ul = '<ul>';

  //Looping through the array
  for (let index = 0; index < motorcycles.length; index++) {
      let motorcycle = motorcycles[index];
      let motorcycleColor = motorcycle.Color;
      let motorcycleType = motorcycle.Type;

      ul += `<li>${motorcycleColor} ${motorcycleType}</li>`;

      console.log(motorcycleColor);
      console.log(motorcycleType);
  }

  ul += '</ul>';
  document.getElementById("section").innerHTML = ul;
}
```

Comment: Could you help me how to do this? I am not familiar with javascript. I started  three days ago with this.

Comment: ok so firstly i just wanna let you know your html code part is correct you are calling the method the correct way, but all you have to do there is put your code inside the function. i put the code above for you to see, now when you click the button reverse, the function is called and then the object is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different questions I think you have here. The first bit that might help is just seeing [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) in action:

```js
const motorcycles = [
  {"Color": "Red", "Type": "Honda"}, {"Color": "White", "Type": "Kawasaki"},
  {"Color": "Blue", "Type": "BMW"}, {"Color": "Black", "Type": "Yamaha"},
  {"Color": "Red & White", "Type": "Ducati"}
]

const sortedMotorcycles = motorcycles.sort( (a, b) => {
  return a.Type.localeCompare(b.Type)
})

console.log(sortedMotorcycles)
```

For string comparisons, [String.localeComparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) does a pretty decent job of alphabetizing by default. Once you have that array created, you can then iterate over it to generate HTML elements. Though you may want to avoid passing strings directly into `innerHTML` because of the script-injection issues that come with it.

Comment: Should set localeCompare() "sensitivity" property so upper/lower case letters sort as desired.

Comment: I want to thank you all who helped me. I fixed my code and it is working. I had been struggling, which is why I decided to get help. Thank you!